# Is it possible to create a store with Nativescript and Prestashop?

Tags: sql-server, web-services, nativescript, prestashop-1.6

Actually, I have an store App for Android and IOS, but they are in differents IDE (Android Studio and XCode), for that reason I will need a Hybrid App to make changes in a only code source.

My question is, if is possible create an App Store in Nativescript with connection with Prestashop 1.6?

Thanks